# Computation of maximum likelihood estimates

Tags: statistics, optimization, partial-derivative, maximum-likelihood

**Question**

Solve for the maximum likelihood estimates of the distribution with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$ and the following *pdf*, where $x > 0$: $$f(x; \alpha, \beta) = \frac {\alpha} {\sqrt {2\pi \beta}} x^{-\frac 3 2} \exp\left[-\frac {(\alpha - \beta x)^2} {2\beta x}\right].$$

Hint: You should be able to write the parameter estimates in terms of $\overline{x}$ and $\overline{1/x}$, where $\overline{1/x} = \frac 1 n \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac 1 {x_i}$.

**My working**

$$\begin{aligned}
l(\alpha, \beta) & = n\ln\frac {\alpha} {\sqrt{2\pi \beta}} - \frac 3 2 \sum^n_{i = 1} \ln x_i - \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac {(\alpha - \beta x_i)^2} {2\beta x_i}\\
& = n\ln \alpha - \frac 1 2 n \ln(2\pi) - \frac 1 2 n \ln \beta - \frac 3 2 \sum^n_{i = 1} \ln x_i - \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac {(\alpha - \beta x_i)^2} {2\beta x_i}\\
\implies \frac {\mathrm{d}l} {\mathrm{d}\alpha} & = \frac n {\alpha} - \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac {2(\alpha - \beta x_i)} {2\beta x_i}\\
& = n \left(\frac 1 {\alpha} + 1\right) - \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac {\alpha} {\beta x_i}\\
& = n \left(\frac 1 {\alpha} + 1\right) - \frac {n\alpha} {\beta} \overline{1/x}\\
& = n\left(\frac 1 {\alpha} + 1 - \frac {\alpha} {\beta} \overline{1/x}\right)\\
\frac {\mathrm{d}l} {\mathrm{d}\beta} & = -\frac n {2\beta} - \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac {2(\alpha - \beta x_i)(-x_i)(2\beta x_i) - (\alpha - \beta x_i)^2(2x_i)} {4\beta^2 x^2_i}\\
& = -\frac n {2\beta} + \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac {(\alpha - \beta x_i)(2\beta x_i) + (\alpha - \beta x_i)^2} {2\beta^2 x_i}\\
& = -\frac n {2\beta} + \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac {(\alpha - \beta x_i)(\alpha + \beta x_i)} {2\beta^2 x_i}\\
& = -\frac n {2\beta} + \sum^n_{i = 1} \frac {(\alpha^2 - \beta^2 x^2_i)} {2\beta^2 x_i}\\
& = -\frac n {2\beta} + \frac {n\alpha^2} {2\beta^2} \overline{1/x} - \frac n 2 \overline{x}\\
& = \frac n 2 \left(\frac {\alpha^2} {\beta^2} \overline{1/x} - \frac 1 {\beta} - \overline{x}\right)
\end{aligned}$$

When
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac {\mathrm{d}l} {\mathrm{d}\alpha} & = 0,\\
\frac {\beta(\alpha + 1)} {\alpha^2} & = \overline{1/x}.
\end{aligned}$$

When
$$\begin{aligned}
\frac {\mathrm{d}l} {\mathrm{d}\beta} & = 0,\\
\alpha^2 \overline{1/x} - \beta & = \beta^2 \overline{x}.
\end{aligned}$$

---

Assuming my score equations are correct and I have not gone wrong anywhere, I am now stuck here. In particular, I am unable to see how I can further manipulate the two equations above to return just $\alpha$ and $\beta$.

Any intuitive explanations will be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Those should be partial derivatives (as you rightly indicated with the corresponding tag). (You can get the symbol for partial derivatives using `\partial`.)

Comment: @joriki yes... I was getting lazy with the notations :P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your calculations look right to me.

You can solve the first equation for $\beta$:

$$
\beta=\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha+1}\overline{1/x}\;.
$$

Substituting that into the second equation yields

$$
\alpha^2\overline{1/x}-\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha+1}\overline{1/x}=\left(\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha+1}\overline{1/x}\right)^2\overline x\;.
$$

Now multiply by $\frac{\alpha+1}{\alpha^2\overline{1/x}}$ (i.e. divide by $\beta$) to obtain

$$
\alpha+1-1=\frac{\alpha^2}{\alpha+1}\overline{1/x}\cdot\overline x\;.
$$

Multiply by $\frac{\alpha+1}\alpha$:

$$
\alpha+1=\alpha\overline{1/x}\cdot\overline x\;.
$$

Now solving for $\alpha$ yields

$$
\alpha=\frac1{\overline{1/x}\cdot\overline x-1}\;.
$$

Finally, substituting into the equation for $\beta$ above yields

\begin{eqnarray}
\beta&=&\left(\overline{1/x}\cdot\overline x-1\right)^{-2}\frac{\overline{1/x}\cdot\overline x-1}{\overline{1/x}\cdot\overline x}\overline{1/x}
\\
&=&
\frac1{\left(\overline{1/x}\cdot\overline x-1\right)\overline x}\;.
\end{eqnarray}

Comment: Thank you! I am not sure why I did not see this. It is funny how as at the higher levels, we can do the more complex mathematics with ease but the simpler algebraic manipulations tend to stump us... ):

Comment: @EthanMark: Indeed, I was surprised that you managed to get all those manipulations of the derivatives right, which seemed to require quite a level of skill, and then didn't see this :-)